# Как в QT регулярным выражению проверить соответствует ли вся строка шаблону?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qregexp

Я пытался делать так,но не работает((

```
   bool Exception::StringInput(QString ar1)
{
   QRegExp* regular1 = new QRegExp("^([a-zA-Z])*$");

    if((regular1->exactMatch(ar1))==false)
       {
        return false;
       }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: 1. Похоже на утечку памяти, объект не удаляется.

2. А почему std::regex не использовать тут?

Comment: Все равно не получется,если я тебя правильно понял(добавил создания regular в функцию)